# photoshop: auto delete black border in images

Tags: photoshop-effects

I have multiple images with black boarder appearing in different area in different image. Now how to auto delete black border in all my images with Photoshop ?

Comment: Are all of the images the same pixel size, like 800px W x 600px H?

Comment: Not really. They are of different width and height.

Comment: can add an image so we can see it? Is this border on a layer or an entire image?

Comment: Its an entire image. I converted it from png to psd. No extra layers.

Answer (score 0):

demo sample: to have an idea i just attached  two images
[image]

[image]